# WooCommerce Api - Override class - Prevent email sent

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

is it possible to override a class of the woocommerce api?

I want to override the class-wc-api-customers.php so that there is no email sent when a new user is created.

Up to now the only possibility I found was to directly edit the file in includes/api/legacy/v3.

If I use this structure (mytheme/woocommerce/includes/api/legacy/v3/class-wc-api-customers.php) in my theme it doesn't work.

I also tried to adjust the woocommerce_created_customer hook in the functions.php so that the email won't be sent when a new customer is created over the rest-api. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'my_customer_created', 10, 3);

function my_customer_created($customer_id, $new_customer_data = array(), $password_generated = false) {
    if (!$customer_id) {
        return;
    }
    return;

    $user_pass = !empty($new_customer_data['user_pass']) ? $new_customer_data['user_pass'] : '';

    $email = $this->emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account'];
    $email->trigger($customer_id, $user_pass, $password_generated);
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: This thread might be an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505663/do-not-send-woocommerce-new-customer-email-if-a-condition-is-true