# Do not send Woocommerce new customer email if a condition is true

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

If i add a new customer to Woo using the REST API i need to avoid sending the new customer email. 
The REST API docs don't talk about this and there's no parameter to set that can prevent the "WC_Email_Customer_New_Account" email

I've tried about 10 different things, I'll list the most recent ones

- Editing the Woo source directly class-wc-emails.php. Not even that works, because when i collect the user meta it's still blank and only has the user ID and nice name
- Creating a plugin that checks an external API and if a condition is met does `remove_action('woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array($email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account'], 'trigger'));`
- Processing everything inside the plugin but i have the same problem as 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I managed to pull it off. My goal was to create a user (customer) via WooCommerce REST API (Customers endpoint) and not to trigger the New Account email.

The first suspect is the `woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account` filter. It gives us the `\WP_User` and `\WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order` objects. The first idea obviously is to just run `get_user_meta()` against the user.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account', function( $enabled, $user, $email ) {
    /**
     * @var bool $enabled
     * @var \WP_User $user
     * @var \WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order $email
     */

    $isOurGuy = 'foobar' === get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'meta_key_is_so_meta', true );
    if ( $isOurGuy ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}, 10, 3 );
```

As it turns out, the REST endpoint handler can only push metadata after the user is created, and email notification is triggered implicitly via a hook in `\WC_Emails()`. It means when our code is running during that email hook, no metadata is available yet.

Next thing to check was to go to the moment before the user is pushed anywhere at all. That would be `woocommerce_before_data_object_save`, an action this time. It gives us two objects, `\WC_Customer` and `\WC_Customer_Data_Store`. The `\WC_Customer` object has our metadata, yay! Let's enclose the existing code into another handler.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_data_object_save', function( $customer, $store ) {
    /**
     * @var \WC_Customer $customer
     * @var \WC_Customer_Data_Store $store
     */

    if ( !( $customer instanceof \WC_Customer ) ) { // I guess other object types may end up here, let's make sure we only get to work with customers.
        return;
    }

    $isOurGuy = 'foobar' === $customer->get_meta( 'meta_key_is_so_meta', true );
    if ( !$isOurGuy ) {
        return;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account', function( $enabled, $user, $email ) use ( $customer ) {
        /**
         * @var bool $enabled
         * @var \WP_User $user
         * @var \WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order $email
         */
        if ( $customer->get_id() !== $user->ID ) { // Is it our guy?
            return $enabled;
        }

        return false;
    }, 10, 3 );

}, 10, 2 );
```

It still does not work. Because this is *before object save*, the user did not exist at the moment when we captured `$customer` into our scope. So `$customer->get_id()` returns 0 (zero). It seems that we overshot in time a bit - need to roll forward. `woocommerce_created_customer` seems like a good candidate. It gives us among other things the new user ID.

Let's compile everything together.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_data_object_save', function( $customer, $store ) {
    /**
     * @var \WC_Customer $customer
     * @var \WC_Customer_Data_Store $store
     */

    if ( !( $customer instanceof \WC_Customer ) ) { // I guess other object types may end up here, let's make sure we only get to work with customers.
        return;
    }

    $isOurGuy = 'foobar' === $customer->get_meta( 'meta_key_is_so_meta', true );
    if ( !$isOurGuy ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Hook into the Customer Created event to capture the new customer ID.
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', function( $customerId ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_customer_new_account', function( $enabled, $user, $email ) use ( $customerId ) {
            /**
             * @var bool $enabled
             * @var \WP_User $user
             * @var \WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order $email
             */
            if ( $customerId !== $user->ID ) { // Is it our guy?
                return $enabled;
            }

            return false;
        }, 10, 3 );
    }, 1 ); // NB: Email is also hooked here with priority 10.
}, 10, 2 );
```

Now let's recap. We hook into the data store and capture the moment a `\WC_Customer` object is saved. We perform custom metadata-based logic to decide whether to proceed. Then we skip to the moment when the user is created to retrieve their ID. Then we hop a little further in time during the "email enabled?" check to actually disable the notification for the given user.

Comment: Excellent work Pavel !
For the record i ended up manually patching one of the methods you mentioned which is a bad idea since every time WC updates it could break my patch
I'll for sure implement your much more elegant solution !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to:

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Email tab

You can find the Options are "New account". Click the manage button.

Uncheck the "Enable this email notification".

Comment: I need to keep the notification for regular registrations but if I create a new user using the REST API there should be no email