# WordPress - WooCommerce API. Disable account setup email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to prevent the new "Your "shopname" account has been created!" email that gets sent when creating a user via the WooCommerce V3 REST API.

[Do not send Woocommerce new customer email if a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505663/do-not-send-woocommerce-new-customer-email-if-a-condition-is-true)

Unfortunately that does not work in V3. The mail is still sent.

Has anyone been able to achieve this? There is no documentation about it. I need to create a custom email for users added in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for this as well and removing the corresponding action `woocommerce_created_customer_notification` does the trick:

```
<?php

function disable_account_creation_email($email_class) {
  remove_action('woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array($email_class, 'customer_new_account'), 10, 3);
}

add_action('woocommerce_email', 'disable_account_creation_email');
```